# Maths quiz with difficulty levels

Tags: python, quiz

I've written this code but it's really long. I really need it to be shorter so can someone please help me! Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
choice=raw_input("What type of quiz do you want to do: maths or science? ") 
topic=open("topic.txt", "a+") 
topic.write(choice + '\n') 
topic.close() 
difficulty=raw_input("What difficulty do you want to play on: easy, medium or hard? ") 
diff=open("difficulty.txt", "a+") 
diff.write(difficulty + '\n') 
diff.close()

score = 0

def answercheck(score, str_answer, int_answer):
    user_answer=raw_input("Select your answer. ")
    if user_answer.upper() == str(str_answer) or user_answer.upper() == str(int_answer):
        print("Well done, that's correct")
        score+=1
        print("Your score is " +str(score))
    else:
        print ("Wrong, it was "+str(int_answer))
        print("Your score is " +str(score))
    raw_input("Press enter to continue")
    return score

def report(score):
    print("Your final score is "+str(score))
    per=str(score)*(100/5)
    print("You achieved "+per+"%")
    if score==5:
        print("You achieved an A*")
    elif score==4:
        print("You acieved a grade B")
    elif score==3:
        print("You achieved a grade C")
    elif score==2:
        print("You achieved a grade D")
    elif score<=1:
        print("You failed")

if choice.lower() == "maths" and difficulty.lower() == "easy": 
    easym=open("mathseasy.txt" , "r") 
    lines = easym.readlines() 
    print lines[0]
    print lines[1]
    print("A. 4"+'\n'+"B. 6") 
    str_answer_one="A"
    int_answer_one=4
    first_score=answercheck(score, str_answer_one, int_answer_one)

    print lines[2]
    print("A. 5"+'\n'+"B. 6") 
    str_answer_two="A"
    int_answer_two=5
    second_score=answercheck(first_score, str_answer_two, int_answer_two)

    print lines[3]
    print("A. 15"+'\n'+"B. 20") 
    str_answer_three="B"
    int_answer_three=20
    third_score=answercheck(second_score, str_answer_three, int_answer_three)

    print lines[4]
    print("A. 13"+'\n'+"B. 15") 
    str_answer_four="A"
    int_answer_four=13
    fourth_score=answercheck(third_score, str_answer_four, int_answer_four)

    print lines[5]
    print("A. 100"+'\n'+"B. 110") 
    str_answer_five="B"
    int_answer_five=110
    fifth_score=answercheck(fourth_score, str_answer_five, int_answer_five)
    report(fifth_score)


if choice.lower() == "maths" and difficulty.lower() == "medium": 
    mediumm=open("mathsmedium.txt" , "r") 
    lines = mediumm.readlines() 
    print lines[0]
    print lines[1]
    print("A. 30"+'\n'+"B. 35") 
    str_answer_one="A"
    int_answer_one=30
    first_score=answercheck(score, str_answer_one, int_answer_one)

    print lines[2]
    print("A. 100"+'\n'+"B. 110") 
    str_answer_two="B"
    int_answer_two=110
    second_score=answercheck(first_score, str_answer_two, int_answer_two)

    print lines[3]
    print("A. 13"+'\n'+"B. 15") 
    str_answer_three="A"
    int_answer_three=13
    third_score=answercheck(second_score, str_answer_three, int_answer_three)

    print lines[4]
    print("A. 30"+'\n'+"B. 32") 
    str_answer_four="B"
    int_answer_four=32
    fourth_score=answercheck(third_score, str_answer_four, int_answer_four)

    print lines[5]
    print("A. 21"+'\n'+"B. 29") 
    str_answer_five="B"
    int_answer_five=29
    fifth_score=answercheck(fourth_score, str_answer_five, int_answer_five)
    report(fifth_score)
```

Here is the data in mathseasy.txt:

```
Welcome to the easy maths quiz.
What's 2+2?
What's 11-6?
What's 5*4?
What's 26/2?
What's 11*10?
```

Here is the data in mathsmedium.txt:

```
Welcome to the medium maths quiz.
What's 5*6?
What's 79+31?
What's 26/2?
What's 4*8?
What's 50-21?
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as your last question?

Comment: @OscarSmith new code though?

Comment: @OscarSmith [different code](https://www.diffchecker.com/EhE93ojA)

Answer (score 3):

You could try making the questions/answers declarative and then the logic surrounding the questions/answers could then be factored out. An easy way would be to store the questions/answers in a list of tuples:

```
data = [("What is 5+5?", 10), ("What is 10+10?", 20) ...]
```

Comment: Isn't that a list of tuples?

Comment: @Mast whoops don't know where my mind went. fixed.

Comment: Good :-) Now I suspect there should be a `(` before the second `"What` as well, correct?

Comment: how would i then check that the useranswer is correct or not? can you do an example of the code for like the first question please

Answer (score 1):

When you have a great deal of `if` statements that assign a second value based on a first one you can use a `dictionary` (look-up hash table) to summarize the associations and use just that:

```
def report(score):
    print("Your final score is "+str(score))
    per=str(score)*(100/5)
    print("You achieved "+per+"%")
    if score==5:
        print("You achieved an A*")
    elif score==4:
        print("You acieved a grade B")
    elif score==3:
        print("You achieved a grade C")
    elif score==2:
        print("You achieved a grade D")
    elif score<=1:
        print("You failed")
```

Can become:

```
NUMBER_TO_LETTER = {
  '5' : 'A',
  '4' : 'B',
  '3' : 'C',
  '2' : 'D'
}

def report(score):
    print("Your final score is "+str(score))
    percentage = str(score)*(100/5)
    print("You achieved "+percentage+"%")
    if 2 <= score <= 5:
        print("You achieved an " + NUMBER_TO_LETTER[score])
    else:  # Score must be less than 1 because 5 is the max.
        print("You failed.")
```

So you can see the data is neatly organized in a table and you can avoid repeating the same message over and over again, that can cause spelling errors (`elif score==4: print("You acieved a grade B")`) and makes code unnecessarily long.

Also you could note that there is an inverse relation between the letter position in the alphabet and the score so:

```
def report(score):
    print("Your final score is "+str(score))
    percentage = str(score)*(100/5)
    print("You achieved "+percentage+"%")
    if 2 <= score <= 5:
        print("You achieved an " + "ABCDE"[5 - score] )
    else:  # Score must be less than 1 because 5 is the max.
        print("You failed.")
```

That is the final and simplest way to code this.